# China entry visa validity on "enter before" date

Tags: visas, china, timezones

My departure time from Amsterdam for Guanghzhou, China will be 13:30 on the 4th. September.  My visa stipulates that I must enter China before the 5th.  Will there be a problem because of the time difference going east?

Comment: Your departure time is irrelevant. What time do you arrive in China?

Answer (score 1):

Although the visa says "enter before", according to the [Chinese Embassy in the USA](http://www.china-embassy.org/eng/visas/faq/), the visa is

> good through 24h00 Beijing Time of the "Enter Before" date unless the number of entries is used up or the visa is revoked by the Chinese government.

If you're flying direct, your flight should arrive around 7h00 on the 5th, Beijing time.

Airline tickets and itineraries almost always give *local* times for all stops, so if yours says you're landing at 7h00, that refers to Beijing time.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what happens if the flight is delayed and I end up arriving 5 minutes past midnight?

Comment: @AleksG: I don't know. Fortunately, OP's flight should be arriving some time in the morning, so they should be safe, unless the delay is really monumental. It'd still be better to have applied for a visa that allowed for some wiggle room, though.